# Spring MVC 3 pagination using PagedListHolder

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, pagination, velocity

I'd like to use [PagedListHolder](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/support/PagedListHolder.html) to do pagination.

I display a list of products on a page. When the next page is requested, I must make a call to a RESTFul service for the results. Hence, there's no "source list" for me. Also, I cannot cache anything in the user session as the lifetime of a list of products is different than the user's session.

Is there some other out of the box implementation in Spring for pagination that I can use?

Answer (score 1):

Check this framework.[Spring Pagination](http://paginationspring.blogspot.com/). But JQuery Data tables is a very widely adopted. Some of the examples that you can look at is [Data-tables](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables)